# Tool for program statistics

Tags: c++, c, statistics, parsing, fortran

Is there a tool which is able to parse my source code (fortran, C or C++) and return statistics such as the number of loops, the average loop size, the number of functions, the number of function calls, the number, size and type of arrays, variables, etc ?

Something similar to [this](http://ctuning.org/wiki/index.php/CTools:MilepostGCC:StaticFeatures) which does not run easily on my architecture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magic Google term is "code metrics". Wikipedia has a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis).

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called nDepend that gives that kind of analysis.

http://ndepend.com/

It is mainly for .net languages, but they do have a version for c++ and Java.

Comment: For c++ you can use cppdepend(http://www.cppdepend.com) and for java the ndepend like is jarchitect (http://www.jarchitect.com)

Answer (score 0):

[SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/) is free and easy to use software for reporting code metrics.

Answer (score 0):

[Understand for Fortran/C/C++](http://www.scitools.com/features/metrics.php)

[image]